# keywindow is not working in iphone 6.0 simulator

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios6

```
[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:myView];
```

The above code is working fine in iPhone 5.1 simulator, but the view is not appearing in iPhone 6.0 simulator. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5):

You have to send makeKeyAndVisable to what ever window you want to add the subview to. Like so:

```
[[self window] makeKeyAndVisible];

[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow] addSubview:view];
```

The key window is the window which will receive user interaction. You can check the apple docs [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIWindow_Class/UIWindowClassReference/UIWindowClassReference.html) for makeKeyAndVisable.

Comment: Did this help with your issue?

Comment: I added a subview at the top level (in front of everything) using keyWindow like Deepak. It worked perfectly (in iOS 7, 8, 9) except during a UIStateRestoring scenario. After coming back to the view controller and decoding (via decodeRestorableStateWithCoder), the subview was no longer visible. I fixed it by putting "[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] windows] lastObject] makeKeyAndVisible];" right before the addSubview. Thanks.